# uploading file in django and python?

Tags: python, django

```
    <input type="file" name="doc-file" multiple/>

   file_path = request.FILES.get('doc-file')
```

My return value of file_path is `None`

But when I do `file_path = request.POST.get('doc-file')` it returns `filename` . What is the best way to upload a file in python and django?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might be forgetting to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag. See [Django's docs on file uploads](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) for details.

Edit: formatting